# multi-dimensional array with two dynamic dimension and one static dimension

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

I know that i can declare an array that has one dynamic dimension like this:

```
double(*LHS)[3][3][3] = new double[M + 2][3][3][3];
```

But I need to declare an array that has "two" dynamic dimension. I checked syntax like below:

```
double (**U)[3] = new double*[M + 2][3];    
for (int i = 0; i < M + 2; ++i) U[i][3] = new double[N + 2][3];
```

But it doesn`t work!

Please help me to properly define a three-dimensional array with to dynamic dimension.

Comment: How about going with the simplicity and using `std::vector`?

Comment: Arrays are a pain in the XXX. Consider using `std::vector<std::vector<std::array<double, KNOWN_SIZE>>>`

Comment: Use `std::array` and `std::vector`.

Comment: Looks like a `std::vector<std::array<double, 27>>` would be enough, where you then map your 3 last coordinates to an index from 0 to 26 (for example `x + 3*y + 9*z`).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Can you copy your answer from the deleted question?

Answer (score 0):

What you could use to call the function

```
void SolveBlockTri(double LHS[][3][3][3], double RHS[][3], int iNRows)
```

using idiomatic c++ techniques with dynamic allocation is:

```
int nRows = 42;
std::vector<std::array<std::array<std::array<double>,3>,3,3> lhs; 
    // = where ever you fill that from;
std::vector<std::array<double,3>> rhs,nRows);

SolveBlockTri(&(lhs.data()), &(rhs.data()), nRows);
```

---

You can also use a templated wrapper function depending on the fixed size part:

```
template<size_t FixedSize>
void CallSolveBlockTri(
    const std::vector<std::array<std::array<std::array<double>
                     ,FixedSize>,FixedSize,FixedSize>& LHS
  , std::vector<std::array<double,FixedSize>>& RHS
  , int iNRows) {
    SolveBlockTri(&(LHS.data()), &(RHS.data()), iNRows);
};
```

---

> But I found it very complicated to declare a 4d dynamic array ( and then deleting it!).

Note that with both of the solutions sketched out above, you don't need to do any manual array allocation using `new` and `delete` operators.
The container classes **[`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)** and **[`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)** will already handle all of that stuff properly.